# How to send js array object to laravel controller function using <a> tag in view?

Tags: javascript, php, laravel

I have cart functionality in my project where IDs of the items are stored in a js array object and the length of the array object is shown in cart. I want to load a view and display the cart items there in the view therefore I want to send the js array object as a parameter to laravel controller function through `<a>` tag when the user clicks on it.

Here is the `<a>` tag which should send the `cart` object to laravel controller:

```
<a href="#" >
    <i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i>
    <span id="cartLength"></span>
</a>
```

Here is the `js` function that increments `cart` array object:

```
function addToCart(id)
{
  if(! cart.includes(id) ) cart.push(id);

  cartLength.html(cart.length);
  $('#successCart'+id).html('Book added to cart.');

}
```

Here is the `<a>` tag that adds the item to cart by calling `addToCart` js function:

```
<a href="#" class="add-to-cart" 
   onclick="event.preventDefault(); addToCart('{{$book->id}}');">
   Add To Cart
</a>
```

Here is the controller function that returns view:

```
public function showCart(Request $request)
{
    return view('cart', ['cart' => $request->cart ]);
}
```

I don't know how to send the `cart` js object to laravel controller function through `<a>` tag and then load the view from there. Any help is appreciated in advance.

Comment: You could do this, but the danger is that if the cart gets large, you will start loosing data as the querystring has a limited allowed number of bytes

Comment: @RiggsFolly : What is the suggested way to do this?

Comment: Post data from a form, or use AJAX (post again) to communicate between browser and backend server

Comment: @RiggsFolly : If I use AJAX then the laravel function will return the view back to the AJAX call but I want to load the view in the browser.

Comment: @AbdulRaheemGhani you could return the view from controller even if it is ajax, and then just use js to render the html (or just call `location.reload()` in the success of the ajax. not very efficient, but gets the job done)

Comment: @AbdulRaheemGhani only return the changed value through ajax use put/patch method to store and return back the updated data then store in js var to show it on page, no need to send view from ajax

Answer (score 1):

If you use an ajax request, on the success of the ajax, collect the (cart items)data and store it in a localstorage. Then display the items onload of the view you want using js.
For example:

```js
//let cart be the array you collected 

let cart = [];
let formdata = new FormData(cart);

$.ajax({
    url:"your/intended/url",
    type:"GET",
    data: formdata

}).done(function (data){
    cartItems = data;

    localStorage.setItem('cartItems', data);
    location.href = "view/cartPage";
})
```